# How to decode partially escaped unicode string in python (mixed unicode and escaped unicode)?

Tags: python, unicode, unicode-escapes

Given the following string:

```
str = "\\u20ac €"
```

How to decode it into `€ €`?

Using `str.encode("utf-8").decode("unicode-escape")` returns `€ â\x82¬`

(To clarify, I am looking for a general solution how to decode any mix of unicode and escaped characters)

Comment: Is the unicode part always escaped? Is there always a space? Are there always exactly 2 parts? Always in this order? So many questions that will change the difficulty. It might be as easy as using `str.split`, or may require a regex

Comment: Sorry, no it's a free from string where unicode characters are mixed with escaped characters, I just narrowed it down to the simplest use case.

Comment: Is this otherwise a valid python string literal? You could do `ast.literal_eval('\"' + str + '\"')` which would work as long as there weren't other things like `str = "\\u20ac  \" bad quote \" €"` in there.

Comment: This is practically impossible. What if the string contains literal `\\u` that isn't part of an escaped Unicode?

Comment: @Barmar in that case I think it will be sufficient to catch `UnicodeDecodeError` raised by `.decode("unicode-escape")` and just add that pard to the output as is`

Comment: Basically I have a big file that's supposed to be utf-8 but also contains `\uXXXX` which I'm trying to "fix". It is not a valid python code. Also if it contains just standalone `\u` then I would be ok with it doing what  `decode("unicode-escape")` does (throws exception),  though I would prefer to just leave it as is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple and fast solution is to use `re.sub` to match `\u` and exactly four hexadecimal digits, and convert those digits into a Unicode code point:

```
import re

s = r"blah bl\uah \u20ac € b\u20aclah\u12blah blah"
print(s)

s = re.sub(r'\\u([0-9a-fA-F]{4})',lambda m: chr(int(m.group(1),16)),s)
print(s)
```

Output:

```
blah bl\uah \u20ac € b\u20aclah\u12blah blah
blah bl\uah € € b€lah\u12blah blah
```

Answer (score 1):

If this is always going to be the format of the string, use `.split`:

```
string = "\\u20ac €"
escaped_unicode, non_escaped_unicode = string.split()
output = '{} {}'.format(escaped_unicode.encode("utf-8").decode("unicode-escape"), non_escaped_unicode)
print(output)
# € €
```

If not, we'll need to get more creative. I think the most generic solution will be to still use `split`, but then use regex to determine if we need to handle an escaped unicode (**assuming the input is sane enough to not mix unicode and escaped unicode in the same "word"**)

```
import re

string = "ac ab \\u20ac cdef €"
regex = re.compile(r'([\u0000-\u007F]+)')
output = []
for word in string.split():
    match = regex.search(word)
    if match:
        try:
            output.append(match[0].encode("utf-8").decode("unicode-escape"))
        except UnicodeDecodeError:
            # assuming the string contained a literal \\u or anything else
            # that decode("unicode-escape") could not handle, so adding to output as is
            output.append(word)
    else:
        output.append(word)
print(' '.join(output))
# ac ab € cdef €
```

Comment: It doesn't sound like it's "sane enough". The question has been updated to say it's a free-form mix.

Comment: @Barmar correct, but hopefully the mix is not within "words". It's hard for me to imagine what kind of input will contain mixed characters within the same word

Comment: Thinking about it, probably parsing out individual `\uXXXX` with regex and replacing them with decoded unicode is the way to go. They won't be separated by spaces, but it's not critical. I was hoping for some simple "decode everything properly in one line" solution without parsing characters manually but probably it's not possible.