# WebScraping for downloading certain .csv files

Tags: web-scraping, request

I have this question. I need to download certain .csv files from a website as the title said, and i'm having troubles doing it. I'm very new on programming and especially with this topic(web scraping)

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BS
import requests

DOMAIN = 'https://datos.gob.ar'
URL = 'https://datos.gob.ar/dataset/cultura-mapa-cultural-espacios-culturales/'
FILETYPE = ".csv"


def get_soup(url):
    return BS(requests.get(url).text, 'html.parser')


for link in get_soup(URL).find_all('a'):
    file_link = link.get('href')
    if FILETYPE in file_link:
        print(file_link)
```

this  code shows all avaibable .csv files but I just need to download those which end up with "biblioteca popular.csv" , "cine.csv" and "museos.csv"

Maybe it's a very simple task but I can not finding out

> https://datos.cultura.gob.ar/dataset/37305de4-3cce-4d4b-9d9a-fec3ca61d09f/resource/456d1087-87f9-4e27-9c9c-1d9734c7e51d/download/biblioteca_especializada.csv

> https://datos.cultura.gob.ar/dataset/37305de4-3cce-4d4b-9d9a-fec3ca61d09f/resource/01c6c048-dbeb-44e0-8efa-6944f73715d7/download/biblioteca_popular.csv

> https://datos.cultura.gob.ar/dataset/37305de4-3cce-4d4b-9d9a-fec3ca61d09f/resource/8d0b7f33-d570-4189-9961-9e907193aebc/download/casas_bicentenario.csv

> https://datos.cultura.gob.ar/dataset/37305de4-3cce-4d4b-9d9a-fec3ca61d09f/resource/4207def0-2ff7-41d5-9095-d42ae8207a5d/download/museos.csv

> https://datos.cultura.gob.ar/dataset/37305de4-3cce-4d4b-9d9a-fec3ca61d09f/resource/392ce1a8-ef11-4776-b280-6f1c7fae16ae/download/cine.csv

> https://datos.cultura.gob.ar/dataset/37305de4-3cce-4d4b-9d9a-fec3ca61d09f/resource/87ebac9c-774c-4ef2-afa7-044c41ee4190/download/teatro.csv

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can extract the JavaScript object housing that info which otherwise would be loaded to where you see if by JavaScript running in the browser. You then need to do some Unicode code point cleaning and string cleaning and parse as JSON. You can use a key word list to select from desired urls.

Unicode cleaning method by [@Mark Tolonen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64071813)

```
import json
import requests
import re

URL = 'https://datos.gob.ar/dataset/cultura-mapa-cultural-espacios-culturales/'

r = requests.get(URL)
search = ["Bibliotecas Populares", "Salas de Cine", "Museos"]
s = re.sub( r'\n\s{2,}', '', re.search(r'"@graph": (\[[\s\S]+{0}[\s\S]+)}}'.format(search[0]), r.text).group(1))
data = json.loads(re.sub(r'\\"', '', re.sub(r'\\u([0-9a-fA-F]{4})',lambda m: chr(int(m.group(1),16)),s)))

for i in data:
    if 'schema:name' in i:
        name = i['schema:name']
        if name in search:
            print(name)
            print(i['schema:url'])
```